# GAS how upload multiple file in google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to upload multiple files into Google Drive Using Google Apps Script.

My code work fine when I want to upload one file

```
  // UPLOAD IMG IN GOOGLE DRIVE
  var url = 'http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2/1-Number-PNG-Picture.png';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get api endpoint
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  if(rc=200){
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx")
    
    if(folder !=null) {
      var file_img = folder.createFile(fileBlob)
      var img = file_img.getUrl();
      }  
    }
   } else {
   var img = "";
  } 

  // APPEND VALUE TO SHEET
  sheet.appendRow([img]);
```

I'm trying to modify the above script in order to upload **multiple files** into google drive, but my code doesn't works.

This is my (not working) code:

```
          // UPLOAD IMG IN GOOGLE DRIVE
          var url = ['http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2/1-Number-PNG-Picture.png', 'https://www.yourcloudworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/number-digit-2-png-transparent-images-transparent-backgrounds-Number-2-PNG-images-free-download_PNG14949.png']; 
    for(var i=0; i<url.length; i++){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(url); 
          var rc = response.getResponseCode();
          if(rc=200){
            var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
             var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx")
            
            if(folder !=null) {
              var file_img = folder.createFile(fileBlob[i])
              var img = file_img.getUrl()[i];
              }  
            }
           } else {
           var img = "";
          } 
         
    
        // APPEND VALUE TO SHEET
         sheet.appendRow(img[i]);

 }
```

> TypeError: response.getResponseCode is not a function

Any help?

Comment: Chane    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(url);   to var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); OR move that line outside the FOR loop and use response[i].getResponseCode(); to read the responsecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `for(var i=0; i<url.length; i++){}else{}` is used. I thought that you might misunderstand the if statement and for loop.
- When you want to compare the value at the if statement, please modify `if(rc=200){` to `if(rc==200){`.
- The response value from `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(url)` is an array.

  - I think that the reason of the error message is this.
- `folder.createFile(fileBlob[i])` is `folder.createFile(fileBlob)`.
- `file_img.getUrl()[i]` is `file_img.getUrl()`.
- When `file_img.setTrashed(true)` is used, the downloaded files are moved to the trashbox. If you don't want to move them to the trashbox, please remove the line.
- I think that when the values are put to the Spreadsheet by one request, the process cost will be low. In your script, I would like to propose to use `setValues` instead of `appendRow`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following modified script. And please set the variable of `sheet`, and the folder ID.

```
function myFunction() {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var url = ['http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2/1-Number-PNG-Picture.png', 'https://www.yourcloudworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/number-digit-2-png-transparent-images-transparent-backgrounds-Number-2-PNG-images-free-download_PNG14949.png'];
  var requests = url.map(u => ({url: u, muteHttpExceptions: true}));
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  var imgs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (response[i].getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var fileBlob = response[i].getBlob();
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx");
      if (folder != null) {
        var file_img = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
        imgs.push([file_img.getUrl()]);
        // file_img.setTrashed(true);  // When this script is used, the downloaded files are moved to the trashbox.
      }
    }
  }
  if (imgs.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, imgs.length).setValues(imgs);
  }
}
```

- When `muteHttpExceptions: true` is used, the script can be run even when an error occurs.

#### References:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)